# Optional function parameters for operation overloading functions c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload pipe operator with no arguments but is binary :( so because i dont like to have argument i think to make the function with optional parameteres (init to NULL).
Is that possible? please suggest me a way to use the pipe operator with no arguments!

```
//example
class oper{
public:
  oper();
  void operator|(oper &t=NULL) { cout<<"im operator |";
}

int main(){
  |    //should print "im operator |"

}
```

Comment: I don't know if C++ would allow such an overload declaration, but the syntax parser would not be happy with a mismatched `|`. Binary operators are just that, binary operators, and so require two explicit operands.

Comment: C++ does not have null references so `oper &t=NULL` is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.   One of the constraints on overloading operators in C++ is that the overloads remain compatible with the default meaning of those operators.

The default meaning of the `|` always involves its use in a binary expression (with one operand to the left and the other to the right, as in `a | b`).   An expression of the form `a|` or `|a` is a syntax error, so it is not possible to overload an `operator|()` to permit such an expression.

It is also not possible to change precedence or associativity of operators.